# Exporting data in csv format depending on filteration

Tags: asp.net, sql, database, csv, export

I want to export the data in csv format depending on the filteration. I have got 2 textboxes of jquery datepicker from which the user can set date format and then use export button to export data between those days, Is it possible to achieve something like that.I am using asp.net 4 & ms sql2008. Any suggestions or assistance will be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

- You need to pass the data from the client to the server.
- Then you need to parse the inputs to date structures
- Then you need to craft a SQL query or use Entity Framework or Stored Proc or such
- Then you need to execute the query on the database
- You then need to loop over the returned data set and create a CSV format
- You then need to set the Response headers to inform the client that you are returning a file (CSV)
- You then need to write the data to the response stream
- Flush the response stream
- Close the Response object

Its not trivial.